# Expo React Native application inside of iOS Simulator keeps reconnecting using socket.io

Tags: react-native, sockets, expo, io-socket

The stack is atm `VueJS`, `React Native` using `Expo`, and `NestJS` for the backend. For convenience, [this repo](https://github.com/felipecrescencio/nest-chat-websockets) contains a working example of VueJS and NestJS parts. The connection from the React Native side (simplified version) is implemented like this:

```
export const useSubscribeToWebsocket = (token: string) => {
  const { socketUrl } = usePlatform()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('open')
    const socket = io(socketUrl)

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connect')
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(authenticate(token)))
    })

    socket.on('error', (error: any) => {
      dlog('error connection=> ', error)
    })

    socket.on('event', (socketEvent: any) => {
      console.log('event ', socketEvent)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.close()
    }
  }, [token])

  return null
}
```

The gateway (socket server) looks pretty straightforward:

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string): void {
    this.server.emit('msgToClient', payload);
  }

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Init');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

The problem is that while the mobile client connects only once (the `useEffect` hook is called one single time, no other logs except `open`), `handleConnection` keeps logging clients with different ids being connected. `connect` is also never logged on the RN side, so I suppose it never connects.
I tested it with VueJS client, and it connects only once (works fine on backend as well), everything works.

Is it a problem related to the simulator only? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, [downgrading](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1402#issue-742414006) to `2.1.1` from `3.0.4` fixed the issue.